# how to combine different tex files to a single file and generate pdf using R

Tags: compiling, r

I have three data frames which I would like to put to pdf. I generate tex files for the three dataframes. So I have three tex files. I would like to combine it and generate pdf in R. Right now I use some online tool manually copy paste all the tex and generate the pdf. Is it possible using R to combine and generate the pdf.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You should look at [`knitr`](http://yihui.name/knitr/). It does what you want.

Answer (score 1):

With the  `Sweave` function of R (or with its successor `knitr`) you do not need make one `.tex` file per each data frame. Instead, you can make a LaTeX file with the `.Rnw` extension  and insert one/several chunk/s of R code (between lines with `<<>>=` and `@`) containing all the data frames and the R code for LaTeX/verbatim printing. One example with `Sweave`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
<<Data,echo=F,results=tex>>=
library(xtable)
# Making 3 data frames
df1 <- data.frame(Foo=c("Foo","Bar","Baz"),Bar=sample(1:49,3,replace=F))
df2 <- data.frame(Stuff=round(rnorm(10),2) ,Thing=round(rnorm(10),3))
df3 <- t(df1)

# show three data frames
xtable(df1, caption=names(df1))
xtable(df2, caption="Data frame 2")
xtable(df3, caption="Trasposed data frame")
@
\end{document}
```

Sweave can convert this is a true `.tex` file. One way is from the terminal:

```
R CMD Sweave my3dataframes.Rnw
```

Then you can compile as any tex file, for example:

```
pdflatex  my3dataframes.tex
```

And read with your pdf viewer:

```
acroread my3dataframes.pdf
```

If you do not need run pdflatex again for solve cross-references, you can make your PDF with a single command:

```
R CMD Sweave -pdf my3dataframes.Rnw; acroread my3dataframes.pdf
```

N.B.: With the editor RStudio you only need to remember where are the buttons to compile and open the PDF.

In any case, the result of the above MWE will be:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot .. :D This is exactly what i was looking for. I will try this out.

Comment: @ArunRaja You're welcome, but note that the usual  way of say thanks in this site is upvote any good answer (of any question)  and  [accept  the best answer](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1852/how-do-you-accept-an-answer)  (only one) to  your own question (of course, if solve your problem o at least deserves more  acknowledgment that a simple  upvote). Accept answers increase also (a little) your reputation in this site.

Comment: Yeah I am regular user of stackoverflow and have points on that. I dont have enough points to upvote here.